# Simple backbone example not updating view

Tags: backbone.js

I'm starting to learn Backbone with this simple example:

```
<div id="counter">unkown</div>
<button id="add-button">ADD</button>

(function($){

   var Counter = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
        count: 0            
     }
   });

   var CounterView = Backbone.View.extend({
       el: "#counter",

       events: {
            "click #add-button": "add"
       },

       add: function() {
           this.model.count++;
           render();
       },

       render: function() {
           $(this.el).text(this.model.get("count"));
           return this;
       },

       initialize: function(){              
           this.render();
       }
   });

   var counterItem = new Counter();
   var counterView = new CounterView({model: counterItem});              

}(jQuery));  // function($)
```

So when the "Add" button is pressed the counter should increase and the view should be updates. I have binded the view and the model and have the click event linked with the add function, but somehow this is not working.

So I guess I'm doing something wrong or I'm just missing some binding?

**EDIT: Fixed as suggested to this ... still not working:**

```
<div class="list">
        <div id="counter">unkown</div>
        <button id="add-button">ADD</button>
</div>  

    (function($){

       var Counter = Backbone.Model.extend({
         defaults: {
            count: 0            
         }
       });

       var CounterView = Backbone.View.extend({
           el: "#counter",

           events: {
                "click #add-button": "add"
           },

           add: function() {
               alert("ADD");
               this.model.set("count", this.model.get("count") + 1);
               this.render();
           },

           render: function() {
               $(this.el).text(this.model.get("count"));
               return this;
           },

           initialize: function(){               
               this.render();
           }
       });

       var counterItem = new Counter();
       var counterView = new CounterView({model: counterItem});                     

    }(jQuery));  // function($)
```

**EDIT: FIXED AND WORKING**

```
<div id="counterHolder">
        <div id="counter">
            <span>unknown</span>
           <button id="add-button">ADD</button>
       </div>
    </div>

    <script>


    (function($){

       var Counter = Backbone.Model.extend({
         defaults: {
            count: 0            
         },

         increase: function(){
             this.set("count", this.get("count") + 1);
         }
       });

       var CounterView = Backbone.View.extend({

           el: "#counter",

           events: {
                "click #add-button": "add"
           },

           add: function() {
               this.model.increase();               
           },

           render: function() {
               $("#counter span").text(this.model.get("count"));
               return this;
           },

           initialize: function(){
               this.render = _.bind(this.render, this); 
               this.render();
               this.model.bind('change:count', this.render);
           }
       });

       var counterItem = new Counter();
       var counterView = new CounterView({model: counterItem});                     

    }(jQuery));  // function($)

    </script>
```

Comment: So annoying when you can't even get the most simple example running and need to post it for help. I'm using Batman.js instead. Buh-bye Backbone!

Comment: This is showing me undefined `$("#counter span").text(this.model.count);` how to access direct property of the model e.g. `this.model.count`

Comment: model properties are accessed via get call (take a look at Backbone documentation) ... this.model.get("count")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The button must be a descendant of the view's `el`

Update your html like below and it should work

```
<div id="counter">
  <button id="add-button">ADD</button>
</div>
```

If you still want to display the count, then add an additional `span`

```
<div id="counter">
  <span id="count" />
  <button id="add-button">ADD</button>
</div>
```

And update your render method

```
render: function() {
  this.$('#count').text(this.model.get("count"));
  return this;
}
```

Comment: This is it ... Have also tried: this.model.bind('change:count', this.render); in the initialize function but with no luck.

Comment: Have also tried this: initialize: function(){
               this.render();
               this.model.bind('change:count', this.render);
           } but it failed with: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined, any idea why?

Comment: don't know why you're getting the undefined error. the syntax looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone models must have their data manipulated through the `get` and `set` methods, not as regular javascript objects. Try

```
this.model.set("count", this.model.get("count") + 1);
```

Or better yet, add an `increment` method to your model class that updates the attribute via `get` and `set` for better encapsulation.

Also, just a note on convention that typically every piece of the DOM that a view changes or binds to should be contained within the parent `el` element. Your view is binding to the add button which is not contained within the view's parent `div`. It seems to be working, but it's basically the event handling equivalent of a global variable.

Comment: Take a look at my edit.. fixes applied as suggested but still no luck the alert() is not invoked.

Comment: Actually, that syntax should look more like:
this.model.set({'count': this.model.get('count') + 1});

Comment: Nope, both `set('key', value)` and `set({key: value})` are correct alternative syntaxes. The former pairs nicely with `get('key')`. http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is a simple javascript error. In `add` you need to call `this.render()` not just `render()`.

Comment: Take a look at my edit.. fixes applied as suggested but still no luck